# Highlight UITableView Without Selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and I'd like to show highlight state but no selection state.

How can I highlight a `UITableViewCell` background on touch (and unhighlight on release), but not show the selection state cell background (I have my own custom selection state)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // You have your code here as you said
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    //Implement custom hilighting code
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `UITableView delegate` method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This would actually deselect the cell though– i just want a custom state.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make the table view unselectable by setting `allowsSelection` to `false`.

Next, create this custom table view cell:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        backgroundColor = .red // or some other color
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        backgroundColor = .white

    }
}
```

Use this custom cell in the table view. You can do something like this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let cell = MyCell()
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
// configure the cell's other stuff
return cell
```